# Forcing value of a pandas series within a bracket to replace values that are too high or low

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for a more efficient way to limit the 
values of a pandas series.

In the example below, each value that's lower than 5 is to
be replaced with 5, each higher value is to be replaced with 25

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': list(range(30))})
df['value'].apply(lambda x: 5 if x < 5 else 25 if x > 25 else x)
```

Is there a built-in in pandas or numpy that does the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
m1 = df['value'] < 5
m2 = df['value'] > 25

df['Status'] = np.select([m1, m2], [5,25], df['value'])
```

Or:

```
df['Status'] = df['value'].clip(5, 25)
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) -

```
np.clip(df.value.values,a_min=5,a_max=25) # use df.value for series output
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the built-in.

There's a clip, clip_lower and clip_upper in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': list(range(30))})
df['value'].clip(lower=5, upper=25)
```